# Weird issue masking 3D arrays iteratively in Python loop

Tags: python, arrays, mask

I have a 3D array, containing 10 2D maps of the world. I created a mask of the oceans, and I am trying to create a second array, identical to my first 3D array, but where the oceans are masked for each year. I thought that this should work:

```
SIF_year = np.ndarray((SIF_year0.shape))
for i in range(0,SIF_year0.shape[0]): 
    SIF_year[i,:,:] = np.ma.array(SIF_year0[i,:,:], mask = np.logical_not(mask_global_land))
```

where `SIF_year0` is the initial 3D array, and `SIF_year` is the version that has been masked. However, `SIF_year` comes out looking just like `SIF_year0`. Interestingly, if I do:

```
SIF_year = np.ndarray((SIF_year0.shape))
    for i in range(0,SIF_year0.shape[0]): 
        SIF_test = np.ma.array(SIF_year0[i,:,:], mask = np.logical_not(mask_global_land))
```

then `SIF_test` is the masked 2D array I need. I have tried saving the masked array to `SIF_test` and then resaving it into `SIF_year[i,:,:]`, but then `SIF_year` looks like `SIF_year0` again!

There must be some obvious mistake I'm missing...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I have solved the problem by adding an extra step in the loop that replaces the `masked` values by `np.NaN` using `ma.filled` (https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/routines.ma.html):

```
SIF_year = np.ndarray((SIF_year0.shape))
for i in range(0,SIF_year0.shape[0]): 
    SIF_test = np.ma.array(SIF_year0[i,:,:], mask =  np.logical_not(mask_global_land))
    SIF_year[i,:,:] = np.ma.filled(SIF_test, np.nan)
```